# How can I override defaults in jQuery Fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I use [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar) on my site, but I need all text in different language. There is piece of code in that plugin:

```
 // function for adding/overriding defaults

 var setDefaults = fc.setDefaults = function(d) {
    $.extend(true, defaults, d);
 };
```

But I have no ideas how I can use it. Please, I need help.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You just override the settings when creating the fullcalendar. Like this:

```
 var options = {
   theme: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   timeFormat: {
    agenda: 'h(:mm)t{ - h(:mm)t}',
    '': 'h(:mm)t{-h(:mm)t }'
   },
   monthNames: ["Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre" ], 
   monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
   dayNames: [ 'Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'],
   dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb'],
   buttonText: {
    today: 'hoy',
    month: 'mes',
    week: 'semana',
    day: 'día'
   }
  };

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar(options);
```

Comment: Am also looking for this. Perfect.

Comment: @vtambourine if this answered your question, please, mark this as the accepted answer. so it can help other users

Comment: Is there a way to just change `buttonText.today` for a specific locale? @tauren

Comment: Update:
I guess one way to do it, is to give it a value from your own locale files.
Worked for me ✅

Answer (score 6):

The properties for this kind of thing are documented here:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/text/

Comment: Oh, that is so obvious, I had to dig into docs one minute longer... Thank you!