# How change nameMonths of fullcalendar to Spanish or any language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, fullcalendar

I hope somebody could answer, is kind of silly question probably...
I would like to change the values of monthnames, monthNamesShort.
I found I can change the values here:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/#time-date-formatting
But can someone share some code of how. I will appreciate it.

Thank you a lot guys.

Comment: http://www.tigraine.at/2011/08/23/localized-fullcalendar-options

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I override defaults in jQuery Fullcalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996152/how-can-i-override-defaults-in-jquery-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 10):

Include `fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js`.

Include `fullcalendar/locale/es.js` for Spain, `locale-all.js` for World.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   locale: 'es'
});
```

[Full Calendar locale docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale)

Comment: 'lang' property was removed. Now is 'locale'. We just need to include the desired location javascript and set this property

Answer (score 9):

When you invoke the calendar just pass the names of the months in spanish:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domingo','Lunes','Martes','Miércoles','Jueves','Viernes','Sábado'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Jue','Vie','Sáb']
});
```

That should do it. You can do the same for any other option you want translated.

Comment: Yep, It worked, thank you now it changed!
Now is time to apply muilti-languages to fullcalendar :D

Comment: If you want to do multi language you can make separate JS files for each language, that way you can use them easily anywhere.

Answer (score 6):

You need to override its default settings:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        monthNames: ['Enero','Febrero','Marzo','Abril','Mayo','Junio','Julio','Agosto','Septiembre','Octubre','Noviembre','Diciembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr','May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dic'],
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`calendar.setOption('locale', 'es');`

Answer (score 1):

For an ES6 build system:

```js
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import esLocale from '@fullcalendar/core/locales/es';
//...
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  locale: esLocale
});
//...
```

This way also translates text in toolbar buttons.

[Locale documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/locale)