# Fullcalendar js script - translating month and day names

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented Fullcalendar script (https://fullcalendar.io/).

Pretty everything works as expected.

The one thing is, I would like to translate english names of months, days of the week.

In downloaded pack, there is folder called "locale". There are translations in it. How can I implement one of them to the site?

Comment: Have you already tried to do something from https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load **specific locale** by inlcluding corresponding js file:

```
<script src='fullcalendar/locale/es.js'></script>
```

Or you can load **all locales** and select the desired one in the plugin init options:

```
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/locale-all.js'></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            locale: 'es'
        });

    });

</script>
```

Please refer to plugin **[locale documentations](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/locale/)** for more details.

Also if you want to override a translation, please refer to this SO question:

> [How can I override defaults in jQuery Fullcalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2996152/4312466)