# fullcalendar 4.0.2 verstion language korean month view issue

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

[image]

I want to remove some text from the Korean version of the calendar view.

For example:

`21일` -> `21`

i.e. I want to remove `일`

But I do not know how. Language packs are useless.

It looks like this has been changed in the 4.0.2 sample.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Try it if you wan't use language packs [Override defaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996152/how-can-i-override-defaults-in-jquery-fullcalendar)

Comment: @MinhNguyen this question is about fullCalendar v4, and the question you've linked to is about v3. They have very different APIs (see [v4 docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) and [v3 docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3#toc) for comparison. The options in the accepted answer there will no longer work in v4.

Comment: For some reason, if you include the data for Korean from the locale JS file, but without actually setting the `locale` setting, then it does what you want: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xeadea?&editable=true&editors=001 . I'm not sure whether to write this as an answer, because it feels like a bug, but that is my observation of how it is working currently. Maybe it will help you.